# Samsung Galaxy Tab 3: It opens with a media player

Tags: samsung

I just wanna ask how to open the default folder again of my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3.

This is what happened:

- First, I connected the USB Plug.
- The tab says: "connected as a media device", but it opens with Rythmbox. I want to open it on the exact folder like "Playlists" "Pictures" "Videos", but when I plug the USB, the Rythmbox quickly appears.

How do I do it again? I'm not really familiar with Ubuntu because I got used on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

1. On your Samsung phone, before to connect it to your PC, go to **Menu** → **Settings** → **Wireless and network** → **USB utilities**.
2. Tap on **Connect Storage to PC**.
3. Connect the USB cable to your PC.
4. Tap on **Connect USB storage**.
5. Use Nautilus - the default file manager in Ubuntu - to view/copy/paste files from your phone.
6. Once finished, tap on **Disconnect storage from PC** to disconnect and unmount drive from Ubuntu.

Source: http://www.tuxtrix.com/2011/07/how-to-access-samsung-galaxy-s-ii-usb.html